# Why do I get this error: Could not load type from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, load, runtime-error

My code compiles with no errors.

In it I have the following interface:

```
namespace IBusinessObjects
{
    public interface INamePluralNameRootObj : INameRootObj
    {
        string PluralName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have the class named Line residing in a different namespace.

There is no reference to INamePluralNameRootObj  in the class Line. (A text search for INamePluralNameRootObj  in the file Line.cs yields no results)

When I try to run the application, the following exception is thrown at the call to the constructor of Line:

> Could not load type 'IBusinessObjects.INamePluralNameRootObj' from
>   assembly 'IBusinessObjects, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.":"IBusinessObjects.INamePluralNameRootObj"}

Note 1: There are plenty of other interfaces in IBusinessObjects that had no problem loading prior to writing this interface.

Note 2: Using Resharper, I did rename the interface a few times. After getting this error I figured resharper may not have renamed everything properly. I then deleted the file and re-created it and am still getting this error.

What is wrong? How do I fix it?

Comment: Does Line implement any interface / inherit any class that implements INamePluralNameRootObj?

Comment: No, however, it uses other classes that do inherit from this interface.

Comment: Ok, now the assembly where Line is defined - does it reference assembly where INamePluralNameRootObj is defined?

Comment: Yes it does. stackoverflow comment is not working so I am adding more text just to see if it will get fixed.

Comment: Strangly when I just typed: "Yes it does" SO would not submit the comment, I had to make the text larger.

Comment: So if you haven't check these let's go to a list of things I do when I have this kind of issues:   1) check if the file is there (either on your working directory or GAC). 2) check if the dll version is the same one your program expects it to be (1.0.0.0 in your case). 3) if the file is there, open it using the ILDASM (Visual Studio Disassembler) and check if the type is there.  4) Go back and check your project references, check if the project that references this dll is referencing the right one.

Comment: 5) Then go deeper and check if the interface is resolved using any IOC mechanism and check if it is correctly mapped to an existing class. 
6) A few times I've seen that a class that implements an interface throws an error during its constructor and then this kind of exception is thrown, debug the other classes that implement your interface just to make sure they are being "constructed" properly.